# About DataGridViewCellEventArgs

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm new for VB. Now, I'm using DataGridViewCellEventArgs on VB. I should change my value after editing; however, the value did not change. If I add second row, then I can change the value.

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, _
                            ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                            Handles dgv.CellEndEdit, dg.CellLeave
  Dim row As Integer = e.RowIndex
  Dim column As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

  If row > -1 Then
            sum = Val(Me.editSUM.Text)
            If Me.dgv.Item(4, row) Is DBNull.Value Then
                Me.dgv.Item(4, row).Value = 0
            End If

            If Me.dgv.Item(5, row) Is DBNull.Value Then
                Me.dgv.Item(5, row).Value = 0
            End If

            If Me.dgv.Item(4, row) Is DBNull.Value OrElse Me.dgv.Item(5, row) Is DBNull.Value Then
                Me.dgv.Item(6, row).Value = 0
            Else

                Me.dgv.Item(6, row).Value = CInt(Me.dgv.Item(4, row).Value) * CInt(Me.dgv.Item(5, row).Value)
            End If

            If IsDBNull(Me.dgv.Item(6, row)) = False Then
                sum += Me.dgv.Item(6, row).Value
            End If
        Else
            For i = 0 To Me.dgv.RowCount - 2
                If Me.dgv.Item(4, i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                    Me.dgv.Item(4, i).Value = 0
                End If

                If Me.dgv.Item(5, i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                    Me.dgv.Item(5, i).Value = 0
                End If

                If Me.dgv.Item(4, i) Is DBNull.Value OrElse Me.dgv.Item(5, i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                    Me.dgv.Item(6, i).Value = 0
                Else

                    Me.dgv.Item(6, i).Value = CInt(Me.dgv.Item(4, i).Value) * CInt(Me.dgv.Item(5, i).Value)
                End If

                If IsDBNull(Me.dgv.Item(6, i)) = False Then
                    sum += Me.dgv.Item(6, i).Value
                End If
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you aren't showing any code.  It's not clear what "using DataGridViewCellEventArgs" means.

Comment: `Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEndEdit, dg.CellLeave` @LarsTech This is my function prototype

Comment: Edit your post with the code.  You seem to be missing the code inside the method.

Comment: @LarsTech I've posted the inside code. I just tried so many times that the first row could not be edited.

Comment: What is suppose to happen?  If I put a number in Column5 or Column6, the result shows up in Column7.

Comment: This function is used to calculate the sum value, but it doesn't read Column5 in Row1. I just used break point to see the value; however, after I edited it, it was still the same value and did not change to what I put in.

Comment: I'm trying to help, but it's difficult to see where the problem is.  I have one row in my grid of seven columns.  I put a "5" in Column5, hit the arrow to the right, and Column7 reads "0".  I then put in a "4" in Column6 and arrow to the right, and Column7 now reads "20".

Comment: Thanks, @LarsTech. Just like what you said. The value of Column6 is "Column4 times Column5".

Comment: I found that the value did not change after I edited it.

Comment: But the column does change in mine, so the problem would be somewhere else.  Just to be clear, Column7 is equivalent to dgv.Item(6, Row) since the indexes are zero based.

Comment: Yes, the original value is zero. I thought that the value might be put in zero somewhere.